# The tag "comparative-linguistics" is spelt wrong

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

I just joined this community because while lurking I found a question tagged "comparitive-linguistics" (sic).

Can we edit "comparative-linguistics" so that it has an "*ra*" instead of "*ri*"?

On a site about language it's kind of funny...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Completed. The typo has now been fixed.